# Docker container can't connect to the internet. But can ping any external ip

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose

Can't ping or connect to any internet domain from docker container
Manjaro linux

dns set in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` on host

`/etc/resolv.conf` in docker container:

```
root@785625d57ad5:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

`ping` from docker contaner (ip is google.com)

```
root@785625d57ad5:/# ping -c 3 172.217.23.142
PING 172.217.23.142 (172.217.23.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.217.23.142: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=51.9 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.23.142: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=51.9 ms

--- 172.217.23.142 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 2 received, 33% packet loss, time 2018ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 51.973/51.980/51.987/0.007 ms
root@785625d57ad5:/# ping -c 3 google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Comment: try to restart docker daemon

Comment: @LinPy already. Don't helps. Restarting host too.

Comment: is the problem still if you use `--network=host` ?

Comment: @LinPy yes, now it works. But in my project we have docker-compose with it's own network

Comment: can you PING the dns servers from inside the containers and from the host ?

Comment: ```sudo docker run busybox nslookup google.com                                                                   
nslookup: write to '8.8.4.4': No route to host
nslookup: write to '8.8.8.8': No route to host
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: then you need to use other dns servers, try the ones you use on your host